# Global application hook for mouse events in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, event-bubbling

Is there any way to register a global event handler for catching mouse events in a Silverlight application? I'd like to avoid subscribing to the mouse event handlers of each FrameworkElement and find a more elegant solution (bubbled events).
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

MouseMove is a bubbling event in Silverlight; have you tried to catch it at the level of the Window ?

Answer (score 0):

All the Mouse events are bubbling events so on the surface of it you should be able to attach event handlers to a root `UserControl` or `Page` element and get the events.

However many of the controls have use for the mouse events and handle these events themselves.  In those cases those events do not bubble any futher.

Comment: I tried this.RootVisual.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(rootVisual_MouseLeftButonDown), true) and it isn't handling the event.  Any idea why?  According to the docs, it seems like it should...